# Porting Actionscript into C++ - has any one crearted any instructions on such topic?

Tags: c++, flash, actionscript-3, translation, papervision3d

Porting Actionscript into C++ - has any one crearted any instructions on such topic? So I vant to try to port papervision3d into C++ for than porting it backwards using alchymy. What do you think of it? Is it possible?

1) Why do I want to port PV3d? It is fast. It is simple. I know and like it. It could push new leap of PV3d interest. It would probably beat current Alternativa 7.5 if g++ and LLVM can optimize code as wall as they say it can.
2) As far as I know there is a way to create real working swf's using Alchemy libs from C/C++ and compiling into swf so it means all event model and display list are probably already there. ([prooving link to video on adobe tv from max develop 2008](http://tv.adobe.com/watch/max-2008-develop/using-c-libraries-in-flash-player-and-adobe-air/)))

Comment: ActionScript and C++ are about as similar as Latin and Japanese...

Comment: C++ already has 3D libraries, papervision3d isn't particularly impressive compared to what C++ already has: why do you want pv3d?

Comment: @zzzzBov: It is known by the community.

Comment: You would be better off using rewriting the AS3 as HaXe and manually make use of inlining and the memory op codes that Flash10 introduced. I believe some people started working on it a while ago..

Comment: @Allan: point is to look on how GCC/G++ will optimize it automatically and to see if it would be faster in some places than moehill api's (which can happen on an average user machin on some web sites)

Answer (score 2):

It's not completely unreasonable to port ActionScript to C++, however, what you will be missing is all the support code that Flash supplies you with. You'd have to reimplement the display list, event dispatching and so on.

Disregarding that, I wouldn't recommend porting Papervision, it's more than a year since the last update and the lead developer has left the project. If anything, I'd recommend looking into the considerably more "alive" Away3D.

Thirdly, the "molehill" version of flash player will have support for proper hardware accelerated 3d (and a software compatibility layer) making your porting efforts rather pointless within a few months.

All in all. Don't do it.

Comment: For me it looks very intresting - If moehill based libs would run slower than alchemy port of simple pv3d on devices with no GPU acceleration...

Comment: @Kabumbus; They won't, because Swiftshader (which is the licensed software renderer in Molehill) will perform far better than PV3D.

Answer (score 1):

Don't.  Even if your port were successful, all you would do is translate ActionScript 3 to C++ to ActionScript 3.  So you'd end up with just about the same code you had in the first place, or possibly even worse, since you'd have a second translation you have little or no influence on.
It would likely be more productive to try to improve the original papervision3d source code, although I wouldn't expect great performance leaps.